# How distribute certificates from software company

Tags: x509

I would ask for help in this matter.
I work in a software company and we're writing a client-server application (like system of documents circulation). It will be delivered as a complete solution as two distributions: client and server.
One of the requirements is the client and server must exchange information in encrypted form.
We decided to use SSL, but have some questions:

1. If we use self-signed certificates then we must generate certificate pair on server side, but how does the client know the server certificate? I want to install all required certificates during installation, but the server certificate is defined only on server installation.
2. If we ship client and server installer with wired server root certificate signed our company certificate in server and client installer - then our company client may create new certificate signed certificate that sign out certificate, that is chain with our company certificate in root - that is bad.
   How can we solve this problem?

I want to ship to client 2 distributions: client, server and after installation they may establish secure channel to exchange information and user should not need to install any certificate manually.

**Noticeable**, this is completely product, we want to sell them to different companies and these companies must have different certificates.